# Backbones use of prototype to define classes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Looking through Backbones source I noticed that classes are defined like this:

`var Model = Backbone.Model = function(...`

Why is Model defined twice I ask myself, a search for Model showed that the prototype of Model is then extended like so:

`_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {`

I did a little test and it seems that if 'Model.prototype' is being extended the changes automatically affect Backbone.Model, what's the reason behind this and why wasn't it instead written written like this:

```
Backbone.Model = function(...
Backbone.Model.prototype.extend(...
```

Hopefully this will lift my understanding of prototypal inheritance up a notch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a shortcut to have a local variable named `Model` which is shorter to type than `Backbone.Model`. Javascript doesn't have a concept of references so both `Model` and `Backbone.Model` point to the exact same object.

Comment: so would `Backbone.Model = function` and then `Model = Backbone.Model` achieve exactly the same thing?

Comment: Yes. Javascript just allows you to do multiple assignments to the same value in one line

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. You don't create a copy of an object when you assign it to more than one variable.

```
var a = {};

var b = a;
a === b // both variables point to (reference) the same object

b.x = 5;
a.x === 5
// updates through one of the variables are thus automatically
// propagated to the other variables that reference the same object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Backbone's `extend` method does exactly what you do by extending function prototype.

Comment: are you saying that Backbone.Model.extend( is like Backbone.Model.prototype = ?